# Why doesn’t my Chromecast device appear in my Wi-Fi settings on my iPad?

Tags: chromecast

My Chromecast device does not show up in my iPad’s Wi-Fi settings any longer. I had taken the device to a different location and network and since returning to original location and network, the device doesn’t show up.

Answer (score 1):

*Chromecast* only appears in the `Wifi/WLAN` settings as long as it is not configured to listen to the local `WLAN` access point. It can only remember one `WLAN` to connect to. Whenever you change your `WLAN`, you have to reconfigure your *Chromecast* to adjust it to the new WLAN settings.

*Chromecast* at first acts as `WLAN` access point to allow for an initial wireless connection for the configuration. Once this is completed, it should not send `WLAN` signals any longer. But I have read reports that this is not always the case. Anyhow, the *Chromecast* `WLAN` signal is no longer used, once the device is configured.

It might be necessary to reset the *Chromecast* to its factory seetings as explained [here](http://allaboutchromecast.com/chromecast-how-to-guide/reset-chromecast-factory-data-reset-fdr/).